# How to hide the bar button item on click of a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigation, back, pushviewcontroller

in my app say i have 2 pages on click on next button(using push view controller) in page 1 it ill navigate to 2nd page ,  in the 2nd page i have a download(UIButton , not in the navigation bar) button , on click of that i need to hide the back button [image: back]

if back button is created by us we can hide it by using the following code

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

but i am not getting how to hide that back button,,can any one help me, thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the back button using the following code:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

See this answer for more details:
[How to hide the "back" button in UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453519/how-to-hide-the-back-button-in-uinavigactioncontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

`self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`