# Hide and Show Bar Button Item

Tags: objective-c

```
  [self setButtonItem:nil];
```

Not hides my bar button item.

And how to show it again?

Answer (score 11):

another option could be **disable and set it color to clearColor**, and then **enable and set it to the original color** again, like this:

```
self.rightButton.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.rightButton.enabled = NO;
```

and later:

```
self.rightButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.rightButton.enabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 9):

Unlike UIViews, there is no "hidden" property you can use here. You'll need to remove your bar button item from your navigation bar or toolbar to hide it and re-add it to show it again.

Using something like this (assuming this is part of the navigation bar):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Unless it's the "back" button, in which case [there's a specific API call you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202698/how-to-hide-the-bar-button-item-on-click-of-a-button?rq=1).

Comment: Yes it's the rightBarButtomItem but this code (that i'd also previous tested) not works.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4,
If you have only one bar button item in the right side you can use this one,

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; //To Hide
>
> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem //To show

Suppose if you have multiple bar button in the right side, for example suppose you have two bar button items(search button and filter button) in the right side of your navigation item. Now the right bar button items are

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchItem,filterItem]

and you have to hide only search button, you can use like,

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [filterItem]

Now what happening is, you can completely hide the search button from the navigation item and the filter item comes in the place of search item

Then if you want to show the hided bar button,

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchItem, filterItem]