# Creating and Removing UIViews Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am learning how to manipulate view displays programmatically, I manage to display a new view in my appDelegate with the following block of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
loginController = [[LoginController alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:loginController animated:NO];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES; }
```

I have added a button in this view that will remove this current view and supposedly programmatically display a new view, however, I only managed to remove the view and not display the new view.

my code to display the second view is the following:

```
HomeController *homeView = [[HomeController alloc] init];
        [self.window addSubview:homeView.view];
        [homeView.view release];
```

Please advise.. I've been searching for hours to no avail, using Switch Views Programmatically, iPhone Views, removeSuperview..

Basically I want to create a simple login flow, at app start I will display my first view (login form), after successful login I want to discard the old view and display the second view which is my home page.

Comment: You have memory leaks in your sample code, `loginController` is never released.

Comment: thanks man, i will add that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with using the `UINavigationController`. In fact, you are almost there.

You already have two view controllers - one for the login page, and one for the home page. In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, push both controllers onto the `UINavigationController`'s stack: first the "home" controller, then the "login" one. Once the login controller detects that the login has been successful, call `popViewControllerAnimated:` or `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to get to the home page.

Comment: since you're using the navigation controller what stops the user from pressing back and getting to the main menu without logging in?

Comment: @JoãoPortela Good point! You need to [hide the "back" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453519/how-to-hide-the-back-button-in-uinavigationcontroller).

Comment: thanks, I got it working following @dasblinkenlight 's advise!