# UINavigationBar Hide back Button Text

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

How can I hide the Back Button Text from an UINavigation Controller?
I will only have the "<" and not "< Back"

Comment: you can not modify default text, instead try navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem to set custom back button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453519/how-to-hide-the-back-button-in-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**In the interface builder**, you can select the navigation item of the previous controller and change the `Back Button` string to what you'd like the back button to appear as. *If you want it blank, for example, just put a space.*

You **can also change it** with this line of code:

`[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Title here"];`

Or in **Swift**:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""`

Comment: Interface builder and Swift programmatic routes did not work for me in XCode 8.3.2, Swift 3

Comment: You can check out my  very [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46153030/3308174) for hiding all back buttons through out the app. P.S.: Requires zero line of code of your own

Comment: If `Back Button` is already blank in IB, just add a space to get ride of `Back` and just show the arrow.

Comment: This will only set the title you specify if the `navigationItem` already has a non-nil `backBarButtonItem`. For completion's sake, you should be creating a custom button, as in the answers below, and assigning that.

Comment: This method currently works only in interface builder. Setting this from code does not work, instead of setting only the title you need to set the whole backBarButtonItem like this: navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Answer (score 94):

You can implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` like this:

#### Older Swift

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
}
```

#### Swift 4.x

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
    }
}
```

`backBarButtonItem` is `nil` by default and it affects next pushed controller, so you just set it for all controllers

Answer (score 83):

You could also do this through storyboard. In the attribute inspector of the navigation item of the **previous controller** you could set " " in the Back button field. Refer Image below. Replace "Your Title here" to " ". By doing this you will achieve the desired result. You don't need to mess with the 'Title' anymore.

Programmatically you could use

`[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@" "];`

where **self** refers to the controller which pushes your desired View controller.

[image: Xcode view controller navigation item]

Sample Before, After Navigation bar

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

Comment: This works perfectly if it's set in storyboards. Just make sure that the navigation bar has a navigation item in it so that it can be set.

Comment: In iOS 9 / Xcode 7.3, setting the `backBarButtonItem` programmatically does not work, but setting it via the storyboard does.

Comment: @ScottGardner, setting `backBarButtonItem` programmatically [works for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37337255/3681880) in iOS 9.

Comment: If you do not have navigation bar in your screen, maybe because it needs to be hidden, you can add navigation item in storyboard, to previous view controller and set its back button to " ".

Comment: This method currently works only in interface builder. Setting this from code does not work, instead of setting only the title you need to set the whole backBarButtonItem like this: navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Answer (score 56):

Setting title of the back button to `@""` or `nil` won't work. You need to set the entire button empty (without a title or image):

#### Objective-C

```
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]];
```

#### Swift

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

This should be done on the view controller that's on top of your view controller in navigation stack (i.e. from where you navigate to your VC via `pushViewController` method)

Comment: thank you, it works! In swift: self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Comment: So this works but with iOS14's tap-and-hold back button, the little floating table view that comes up no longer shows titles of the view controllers ;(

Answer (score 32):

Add the following code in viewDidLoad or loadView

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

I tested it in iPhone and iPad with iOS 9

Comment: This didn't clear title of previous view controller?

Comment: Don't use because it will remove the last screen title

Comment: If you need to do it from current view controller then to avoid removing the title from previous vc you should rather do: navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Answer (score 31):

Another solution to this issue for situations where you have a great deal of view controllers is to use a `UIAppearance` proxy to effectively hide the back button title text like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *navBarButtonAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil];

[navBarButtonAppearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    NSFontAttributeName:            [UIFont systemFontOfSize:0.1],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor] }
                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This solution will render the text as a tiny clear dot, similar to manually setting the back button title to `@" "`, except that it affects all nav bar buttons.

I don't suggest this as a general solution to the issue because it impacts all navigation bar buttons. It flips the paradigm so that you choose *when to show* the button titles, rather than *when to hide* the titles.

To choose when to show the titles, either manually restore the title text attributes as needed, or create a specialized subclass of `UIBarButtonItem` that does the same (potentially with another `UIAppearance` proxy).

If you have an app where most of the back button titles need to be hidden, and only a few (or none) of the nav buttons are system buttons with titles, this might be for you!

(Note: the font size change is needed even though the text color is clear in order to ensure that long titles do not cause the center nav bar title to shift over)

Comment: shouldn't it affect all other buttons in navigation bars including left/right bar button items?

Comment: Yes, he didn't specify a more comprehensive requirement.

Answer (score 25):

I tried some above and below but they didn't work. This worked for me:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
}
```

Comment: If you need to do it from current view controller then to avoid removing the title from previous vc you should rather do: navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Answer (score 16):

You can add this Objective-C category to make all "Back" buttons created by a navigation controller have no text. I just added it to my AppDelegate.m file.

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (Customization)

/**
 Removes text from all default back buttons so only the arrow or custom image shows up.
 */
-(UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem
{
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}

@end
```

PS - (I don't know how to make this extension work with Swift, it was having weird errors. Edits welcome to add a Swift version)

Comment: This give the title "Back" not hide the title

Comment: This works on iOS 9.0 - 10.3.3, but on iOS 11+ does not work.

Comment: You should not use a category/extension to override a method. This can easily break at any time in future.

Answer (score 14):

The only thing which works with no side-effects is to create a custom back button. As long as you don't provide a custom action, even the slide gesture works.

```
extension UIViewController {
func setupBackButton() {
    let customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = customBackButton
}}
```

Unfortunately, if you want all back buttons in the not to have any titles, you need to setup this custom back button in all your view controllers :/

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupBackButton()
}
```

It is very important you set a whitespace as the title and not the empty string.

Answer (score 11):

The current answer wasn't working. I wanted to **remove the title** entirely, yet the text "back" wasn't going away.

Go back to the previous view controller and set its title property:

```
self.title = @" ";
```

***ONLY*** works when the previous View Controller does not have a title

Comment: It actually ended up working for me *without* spaces; just good old empty string: `@""`.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg, When I first came up with the solution it was earlier in Xcode 5. With a space was the only way it worked, which is why I included it in the sample code. The Xcode 6 update must have included it. Good to know - thx

Comment: I also used my approach, which is still working, and actually removed the standard back arrow too.

Answer (score 9):

to remove the Text from backbutton programmatically, used below Code this will work form xcode7 and above.

**self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @" ";**

or

manualLy in storyboards, select the navigation bar on the view controller and put " " in back button text.

this will work. thanks

Comment: This one will remove navigationItem title too

Comment: I edited your answer to this : `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = " "` in Xcode 9 and worked !

Comment: If you need to do it from current view controller then to avoid removing the title from previous vc you should rather do: navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

```
viewController.navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
```

Comment: Available in iOS 14.0+

Answer (score 6):

The problem with most solutions here is that setting an empty text on the back item does not work well with the new functionality for long press on back buttons. Instead of showing proper titles, it is just showing an empty list

[image: Empty list on long pressing a back button]

Instead, you can use the **new button display mode for iOS14** or rely on the **new appearance APIs for iOS13** , to set the **text to size 0**. Note that some people are playing with the color (clear), that doesnt work well either because it uses the space and removes it from your titles. If the title is long enough, you will see it clipped

Resulting code:

```
public extension UINavigationBar {
    func fixAppearance() {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            topItem?.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
        } else if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let newAppearance = standardAppearance.copy()
            newAppearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.clear,
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0)
            ]
            standardAppearance = newAppearance
        } else {
            topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to call that method when view controllers are presented, so either you call it from a base class (on `viewWillAppear` for example) or you add some delegate to the navigation controller like in other answers of this post.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative way - use custom NavigationBar class.

```
class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    var hideBackItem = true
    private let emptyTitle = ""

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if let `topItem` = topItem,
            topItem.backBarButtonItem?.title != emptyTitle,
            hideBackItem {
            topItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: emptyTitle, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }

        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

}
```

That is, this remove back titles whole project.
Just set custom class for UINavigationController.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of answers already, here's my two cents on the subject. 
I found this approach really robust. 
You just need to put this in viewController before segue.

**Swift 4:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set Title of the Previous VC to " " string with space. and title with the back button will be replaced with single space string.

```
Self.title = " "
```

On Back press again reset the title to original one in the viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom `NavigationController` that overrides `pushViewController`

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {  
  override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
      UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're targeting **iOS 13** and later you can use [this new API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance/3198030-backbuttonappearance) to **hide the back button title globally**.

```
let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]

UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance
```

Comment: This is not optimal. If a user taps the label with the clear text, the back action is still triggered.

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything in this post. The only working solution is @VoidLess's

Here is the same answer but more complete

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.delegate = self
    }
}


// MARK:UINavigationControllerDelegate
extension CustomNavigationController {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my resolution for iOS11, I change the appearance of UIBarButtonItem in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-100, 0), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

You can't change Y offset, because it will change the back bar button's position too in iOS11, but it's OK in iOS10 and below.

Comment: It works but during animation you can see previous title moving on left. It looks a little bit buggy.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.1**
You can do this by implementing the delegate method of UINavigationController.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, 
                          willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    /** It'll hide the Title with back button only,
     ** we'll still get the back arrow image and default functionality.
     */
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, 
                               action: nil)
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift3,

If you set global setting

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // ..

    let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)


    // ...

}
```

Comment: Note that this will also change the color to transparent for all other bar buttons that you might have somewhere in your app, not only back buttons.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to hide back button title globally.

You can swizzle `viewDidLoad` of `UIViewController` like this.

```
+ (void)overrideBackButtonTitle {

    NSError *error;

    // I use `Aspects` for easier swizzling.

    [UIViewController aspect_hookSelector:@selector(viewDidLoad)
                              withOptions:AspectPositionBefore
                               usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo)
    {

        UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)aspectInfo.instance;

        // Check whether this class is my app's view controller or not.
        // We don't want to override this for Apple's view controllers,
        // or view controllers from external framework.

        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([vc class]);
        Class class = [NSBundle.mainBundle classNamed:className];
        if (!class) {
           return;
        }

        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
        vc.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

    } error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%s error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[self class] overrideBackButtonTitle];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset.init(horizontal: -300.0, vertical: 0.0)
}else{
      let barButtonApperance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barButtonApperance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:AppColor.PrimaryGray.value], for: UIControl.State.normal)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this because I had a custom navigation controller.
I was able to remove the back item text in all view controllers with this code in my custom navigation controller class
`override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       self.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
    }`

This removes all of the back item titles using this custom navigation controller.

Comment: Update for this:
this works but there is an odd lag in loading that bothers me. I've now added this
 'let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
        BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)'
in the App delegate didLaunchWithOptions, and it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11, we found that setting `UIBarButtonItem` appearance's text font/color to a very small value or clear color will result other bar item to disappear (system does not honor the class of UIBarButton item anymore, it will convert it to a `_UIModernBarButton`). Also setting the offset of back text to offscreen will result flash during interactive pop.

So we swizzled `addSubView`:

```
+ (void)load {
    if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
        [NSClassFromString(@"_UIBackButtonContainerView")     jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(addSubview:) withMethod:@selector(MyiOS11BackButtonNoTextTrick_addSubview:) error:nil];
    }
}

- (void)MyiOS11BackButtonNoTextTrick_addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    view.alpha = 0;
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (id)view;
        [button setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [self MyiOS11BackButtonNoTextTrick_addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setNavigationItems{
     UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"**Your title here**" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked)];   
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=leftBarButtonItem;
}
-(void)backButtonClicked{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The back text come from last View Controller's `navigationItem.title`，and `navigationItem.title` is automaticly set by `self.title`. So easy way to solve the problem is hook `setTitle:`，make sure `navigationItem.title = @""`

Put this code at `AppDelegate.m` will make it ok。

```c
    [UIViewController aspect_hookSelector:@selector(setTitle:)
                              withOptions:AspectPositionAfter
                               usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo, NSString *title) {
        UIViewController *vc = aspectInfo.instance;
        vc.navigationItem.titleView = ({
            UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            titleLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
            titleLabel.text = title;
            titleLabel;
        });
        vc.navigationItem.title = @"";
    } error:NULL];
```

*More details at https://www.jianshu.com/p/071bc50f1475 （Simple Chinease）*

Answer (score 0):

My solution: 
- XCode: 10.2.1
- Swift: 5

- Parent viewcontroller:

  - self.title = ""
- Child viewcontroller:

  - self.navigationItem.title = "Your title" // to set title for viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

XCode 11.5 Swift 5

A very simple - though perhaps a little hacky - way of doing
programmatically this if you don't need the custom back button is to set the font size equal to zero in the view controller you're pushing onto the stack, calling something like  this from viewDidLoad

```
private func setupNavBar() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    
    let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 0)!]
    appearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance

    navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UINavigationControllerDelegate**'s `navigationController(_, willShow:, animated:)` method implementation did the trick for me.

Here goes the full view controller source code. if you want to apply this throughout the app, make all viewcontrollers to derive from `BaseViewController`.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    // Controller Actions
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateNavigationBar()
    }
    
    //This is for custom back button image.
    func updateNavigationBar() {
        let imgBack = UIImage(named: "icon_back")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = imgBack
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = imgBack
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    }
}

extension BaseViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    //This is to remove the "Back" text from back button.
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15, I could only get the back button text to disappear using the bar appearance API. It seems like overkill, but I've ended up reusing this all over an app. Here's an extension with a bunch of other useful pieces to customize a nav bar. Setting `backButtonTextColor` to `.clear` does the trick for this particular issue.

```
extension UIViewController {
    @objc func setNavBarAppearance(with backgroundColor: UIColor,
                                   titleColor: UIColor? = nil,
                                   shadowColor: UIColor? = nil,
                                   tintColor: UIColor? = nil,
                                   backButtonTextColor: UIColor? = nil) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    
        if let titleColor = titleColor {
            appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor]
        }

        if let shadowColor = shadowColor {
            appearance.shadowColor = shadowColor
        }

        if let tintColor = tintColor {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        }
    
        if let backButtonTextColor = backButtonTextColor {
            let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
            backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: backButtonTextColor]
            appearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance
        }

        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Call it in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` like:

```
setNavBarAppearance(with: .systemBackground, backButtonTextColor: .clear)
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally found perfect solution to hide default back text in whole app.

Just add one transparent Image and add following code in your AppDelegate.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "transparent"), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

Answer (score -2):

The following method works on iOS 11 and is safe to not crash on other iOS versions.
Doing this may get your app rejected in App Store review since both UIModernBarButton and UIBackButtonContainerView are private APIs.
Place in AppDelegate.

```
    if
        let UIModernBarButton = NSClassFromString("_UIModernBarButton") as? UIButton.Type,
        let UIBackButtonContainerView = NSClassFromString("_UIBackButtonContainerView") as? UIView.Type {

        let backButton = UIModernBarButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIBackButtonContainerView.self])
        backButton.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

This is from my xamarin.forms code, the class derives from `NavigationRenderer`

```
NavigationBar.Items.FirstOrDefault().BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem( "", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
```

Answer (score -6):

Swift version, works perfectly globally:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

        return true
    }
```

Comment: You should add, that this will hide **all** text also rightBarButtons and leftBarButtons, which do not go back.

Comment: this is not a `solution`. As @limfinity pointed, it will change it universally for all the UIBarButtonItem's throughout the app