# Is there a way to hide the text on the back button in UINavigationBar universally?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Seemingly the accepted way of changing the back button text for a `UIViewController`'s navigation bar is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853712/998117), essentially setting the text to nothing on the previous view controller.

However, this has to be done on every view controller. Worse yet, the button still takes up quite a bit of horizontal space (past what you would logically expect) as if there's still text there.

Is there a way, say in a `UINavigationController` subclass to hide the back button text in every view controller and make the area occupied by the back button more or less just the size of the "<"?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `UINavigationBar`. In your subclass, override `backItem` to return a `UINavigationItem` with an empty `title`. You might have to use a string containing a space rather than the empty string.

Specify that subclass as the custom class of the navigation bar in your storyboard, or (if you create the navigation controller in code) using `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`.

Comment: Would this solve the issue of the back bar button occupying far more space than it should? It seems like even with `""` set as the text, it still takes up as much space as if there was two or three characters in the title.

Comment: Apple specifies a minimum button touchable area of 44 x 44. I would assume this has something to do with that.