# Not Remove Navigation back button title

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

[image]

I am IOS Developer. I am using navigation controller. If I push to next page then Back button title always Show "Back". I try all this method for remove  titles in viewWillAppear, viewDidload like below. But it is not working for me.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:nil action:nil];
```

or

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@""];
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"";
```

or

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title =@"";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think u r using storyboard yes/no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this,

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) 
                                                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

or use like this,

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style target:nil action:nil];
```

or use like this,

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    self.backItem.title = @"";
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

**Swift**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().UIOffsetMake(0, -60)
```

or use like

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style, target: nil, action: nil)
```

For additional information, Please see [this].([UINavigationBar Hide back Button Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853617/uinavigationbar-hide-back-button-text))

Comment: thanks for the fast answer this actually solved my Problem.

Comment: @BhumeshPurohit - tanx buddy

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
```

You can also do it in Storyboard, select your View Controller's Navigation Item, and set  it's Back Button property to " " (one spacebar character).

**Both ways should be done on the View Controller you're segueing from.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to add an custom image for back button like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_back"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(invokeButtonBack:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

with `header_back` is your custom image for back button.
If you using a custom base viewcontroller (maybe tableviewcontroller) simplify creat a function like this:

```
- (void)createBackButton{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_back"]
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(invokeButtonBack:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

Then call it in your viewcontroller with: `[self createBackButton];`
Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following line in ViewDidLoad.

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```