# how to check the navigationcontroller title

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing `UINavigationController` based application. I placed the title to separate the pages. If I move to the first page , I set the title

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"First";
```

If I move to the second page

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"Second";
```

and it is working fine. But as I move to the third page, I'm setting the title yet it shows  **< Second    Third**

Anyone knows how to check if the `UINavigationController` title is present or not.

Comment: @anbu: Can you please suggest any idea?

Comment: your question is not clear  can you elaborate p;z

Comment: I created three pages based on UINavigationController, if i move to the first page, i set the title as First, as well as i move to the second page it shows the title as Second, if i move to the third page, it shows Second Third as Title ,what i need is, the third page title should be Third.

Comment: in **< Second    Third**, Second is back button of previous view controller and "Third" is title of your view controller

Comment: @rohit :how to resolve that

Comment: @user2384583 - check once Rohit comment

Comment: else u need to remove back button title,

Comment: You can change the second text as "Back" or Simply put the < button

Comment: @rohit,@anbu:i want to remove the title of Second.

Comment: If you are pushing to third, then you should set the back bar button title as @Anbu.Karthik answer. Show the code of how you are moving to third.

Comment: Remove back button title -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/23853617/4970453

Comment: @user2384583 check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your Third ViewController add the following code in `ViewDidLoad` and try once

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@" "];
```

Comment: for additional information see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853617/uinavigationbar-hide-back-button-text

Comment: [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@" "];
    
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
    


    self.navigationItem.title=@"Third";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

Comment: yeah.Third Visible. but Second also visible.

Comment: can you give your project i will check

Comment: i am leaving from office. will update u in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

in your `ThirdViewController` use the following code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@""];
```

it works for you

Comment: the questioner not need the title , he need to remove the back button title , can you update your answer once

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code

when you are move second tho third

in second view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" "
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                      target:nil action:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working.... Thank you everyone..

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.title = @"Back";
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.title = @"Title of your navigation bar";
}
```