# How do I remove the navigation bar title?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, navigationbar

I can't seem to find the proper code to remove the title(s) on my navigation bar. Any ideas?

Comment: How is the title being set? Just don't set the title and there won't be one.

Comment: Change Color https://stackoverflow.com/a/621185/6822622

Comment: remove back button title :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853712/6822622

Answer (score 3):

You have probably set the title in Storyboard. Remove it in Storyboard or set the title to `nil` in `viewDidLoad()` of your `UIViewController` instance:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically set navigation bar title empty string in `viewDidLoad()` of your `UIViewController()`  instance:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism to remove the title in code is always like `.remove()`.
In Swift5, we have `titleView?.removeFromSuperview()` to remove the title view and `title?.removeAll()` to remove the text in title:

```
//M: find your controller -> tabBarController -> navigationItem -> titleView/title -> remove
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView?.removeFromSuperview()
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title?.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can hide the title bar (navigation bar) of a UINavigationController by using the setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:) method. Here's how you can do it:
write it after super.viewDidLoad()

```
 if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
        // Hide the navigation bar
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
```