# Adding multiple buttons in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

My app requires me to add multiple buttons in my navigation bar.
Here is an image of what my nav bar looks like

[image]

How do i achieve this type of design?

Comment: Is the circular image in the on the left supposed to be part of of the "back button" (instead of showing the title of the previous view controller)?

Comment: no the circular button and the back button are different entities but what if i want to increase of decrease spacing between those two entites? @MikeMertsock

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your view controller's [`navigationItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem) in various ways to achieve this design.

#### Left side

To allow additional buttons next to the system "back button" on the left:

```
navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

This allows you to add a left bar button item for the circular image:

```
navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(imageItem, animated: trueOrFalse)
```

`imageItem` would be a UIBarButtonItem initialized with a customView or image, as discussed in some of the other answers here.

For the back button itself, to achieve a simple "<" without showing the title of the previous view or showing "< Back", you can open the storyboard and set the Back Button text of the previous view controller to a single space, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853712/795339).

#### Title area

For the title area, as discussed in the other answers:

```
navigationItem.titleView = (a custom view)
```

#### Right side

For the right side, you can add multiple buttons:

```
navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([button1, button2, button3, button4], animated: trueOrFalse)
```

Here, button1, button2, button3, and button4 are each UIBarButtonItems. You would likely [initialize these buttons with images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617163-init).

Looks like you also will want to set the tintColor of the navigation bar to black, so that the bar buttons are rendered in black:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
```

All of this code would be done in the view controller, usually in `viewDidLoad`, unless you need to dynamically change which buttons are shown as the content of your view controller changes.

Comment: what if i want to customize spacing between these bar button items and what labels instead of buttons ?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
let callImage   = UIImage(named: "call")!
let videoImage   = UIImage(named: "video")!
let searchImage = UIImage(named: "search")!

let callButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: callImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapCallButton))
let videoButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapVideoButton))
let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapSearchButton))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [callButton, videoButton, searchButton]
```

**Selector methods**

```
func didTapCallButton(sender: AnyObject){
    ...
}

func didTapVideoButton(sender: AnyObject){
    ...
}

func didTapSearchButton(sender: AnyObject){
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do i adjust spacing and distance between these bar button items ?

Comment: @NikeshHyanju you can create a UIBarButtonItem with a system type of fixed space or flexible space

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own view and put down your Images, Labels, etc...
After that, you write:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = yourView
```

Comment: How do i resize my view to the size of navigation bar

Comment: try this: let titleView = UIView()
        titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationItem` has a property called `rightBarButtonItems`, this expects an array of `UIBarButtonItem` which would in your case be each of your buttons.

You can use the initialiser on `UIBarButtonItem` to specify the image and style:

> *init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: Any?, action: Selector?)*
>
> Initializes a new item using the specified image and other properties.

On your view controller you can access the navigation item through the accessor `navigationItem`, if you embed your view controller inside a `UINavigationController` you will need to access the navigationItem on that instance and not the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add UIView in navigation bar so that you can add multiple buttons in that view.