# How to hide title near the navigation icon in navigation bar ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an ios application using storyboard and swift. I have a small issue with the title near the navigation icon not hiding.I am setting the code like `self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""`

But it also not worked. I have attached the screenshot. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)  i put like but navigation icon hided

Comment: you will find the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853712/9427558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
```

- Note : This will remove back button title of current viewController and also it will clear the title of previous ViewController (where the back button is going to), so you have to set the title in `viewWillAppear` of previous ViewController if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do. But first a little of theory. The `backBarButonItem` does not affect the current `ViewController`, it affect the next in the stack of the `UINavigationController`. I will give you an example. If you have the `ViewController` `A` and the `ViewController` `B`, then to accomplish your task, you set the `backBarButtonItem` in `A` with a **blank** space in the `title`. Then when you go `A -> B` you will see only the arrow in the top left corner.

Exist two way to solve this issue, one in the `storyboard` and the other is in code.

1. For the `storyboard` you need to set like in the next  picture the **Back Button** title with an single space like you can see

[image]

2. The second way is in code, but for this you need an extra code get the *dismiss* appropriately

First put this code anywhere in your project

```
extension UIViewController {
    @IBAction func unwind(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
    {

    }
}
```

With that, then in `A ViewController` you can do then this:

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(unwind(_:)))
    }


}
```

Good coding. Best regards

Comment: Okay but I am navigating one storyboard view controller to another view controller.i have set the first way you said but its not working. My storyboard have only one view controller and navigation controller

Comment: Try in code then. Majorly of the time i use the code version

Comment: Any success?? Or nothing

Comment: nothing success but i was fixed by setting topitem.tittle=""