# Reset Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, segue

I have segued to a view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller for title purposes. I want to remove the button which allows me to go back to the last view controller without having to unembed the navigation controller. How might I do this?

[image: I want to remove the grade button]

Comment: This should do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453519/how-to-hide-the-back-button-in-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: you want to completely remove it? or just do not show the title, but only the `<`, and with the functionality of going back?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by accessing the navigationItem of the UINavigationController, and using the `setHidesBackButton(_:animated:)` method.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

You can read about the method in Apple's documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624934-sethidesbackbutton